# having problem upgrading 5 year old django project

Tags: python, django, encoding, upgrade, rebuild

i am trying to use pip freeze > requirements.txt file and in my requirements.txt. i see HUL written between every word and version there. please help[image]

i don't know what to try google not helping much

Comment: I'd guess that it's `␀` (U+0000,  *Null*) character; Open the file using `utf-16-le` encoding (or, better, generate the file using `utf-8`).

Answer (score 0):

Try [pipreq](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)

```
pip install pipreq
```

To generate requiremnts file

```
pipreqs>requirements.txt
```